# Advice for Queue Channel send timeout

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to specify an advice, like RequestHandlerAdvice, for QueueChannel's doSend method.

I have a Filter sending a data to a queue channel (with send-timeout of 0). When the queue is full, this throws an exception. I would want to trap this exception instead of throwing it to the sender.

```
<int:filter id="filterA" input-channel="channelA" output-channel="channelB" 
        method="fltrBsdOnCondtn" ref="fltr" send-timeout="0" />

<int:channel id="channelB">
    <int:queue capacity="5000" />
</int:channel>
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Satheesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom advice on the queue channel, using normal Spring AOP configuration.

But, it's probably easier to just put an `error-channel` on whatever is starting the flow (e.g. a `<gateway/>`) and handle the error there.

Comment: Thank you, Gary! I will go with the 'error-channel' option.